Expected number of full neighbors of a Voronoi cell in $\mathbb{R}^3$
Given a Voronoi diagram in three dimensions, what is the expected number of full neighbors E(C) of a Voronoi cell?

Two adjacent cells are considered full (or Gabriel) neighbours in R^3 if the line joining their generator points intersects their common face [1]

What I have tried
I came across table 5.5.2 in [1] that claims E(C) is exactly 8.

I cannot understand how this number of derived. Cross referencing with figure 5.5.15 shows empirical evidence in the form of a unimodal histogram with mean ~8. But I can't understand the process that was used to derive it.

As an experiment, this python script generates 1000 uniform points in R^3, constructs a Voronoi diagram, and counts the number of adjacent cells. This, however, returns a value closer to E(F), the number of faces of a typical cell, not the number of neighbors, which I am trying to empirically prove.

import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import Voronoi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

points = np.random.rand(1000, 3) 
vor = Voronoi(points)
neighbors = {}
for simplex in vor.ridge_points:
    i, j = simplex
    if i not in neighbors:
        neighbors[i] = []
    if j not in neighbors:
        neighbors[j] = []
    neighbors[i].append(j)
    neighbors[j].append(i)
neighbor_counts = [len(neighbors) for neighbors in neighbors.values()]
average_neighbors = np.mean(neighbor_counts)
plt.figure()
plt.hist(neighbor_counts, bins=range(min(neighbor_counts), max(neighbor_counts) + 2, 1),
         edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel("Cell 'Neighbour' Count")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.grid()
plt.show()

[1] Spatial Tessellations: Concepts and Applications of Voronoi Diagrams
